# Solidity - check PoW difficulty

Tags: solidity, blocks, difficulty, powhash

If given block data and a difficulty number, is it possible to verify that the header produced is at or above the provided difficulty from within Solidity?

For example, suppose I have the following block data:

```
{
  author: "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830",
  difficulty: 1543338950559758,
  extraData: "0xe4b883e5bda9e7a59ee4bb99e9b1bc",
  gasLimit: 6713094,
  gasUsed: 6700572,
  hash: "0x569f4e8c86626f4047d920c574420ffd52310d8a359155e6a246c9576ce1037e",
  logsBloom: "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",
  miner: "0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830",
  mixHash: "0x33319b1b81b39559f51af665b57401a8fc1abecbb03b2684422994d85a5cb18e",
  nonce: "0x81da15480b0a96ee",
  number: 4637262,
  parentHash: "0xf66b4d7eced1ef88dfe668a9edc2b8ce43d92d71d55752b6c27e859bfa9bb86a",
  receiptsRoot: "0x0bf5737fd1516ecb4609ca396041b887e6137938db3a00ffb008cdfd7d67f603",
  sealFields: ["0xa033319b1b81b39559f51af665b57401a8fc1abecbb03b2684422994d85a5cb18e", "0x8881da15480b0a96ee"],
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 26022,
  stateRoot: "0x29738568ddaa5a4696e7eebd78cd2150d4c8267744a2cb4d39e46cca71546b65",
  timestamp: 1511865007,
  totalDifficulty: 1.587541539031876898867e+21,
  transactionsRoot: "0x13a5b20cae65672b7bddadbae5161978ded6303878a1514b34ac6474866e37c3",
  uncles: []
}
```

How would I verify the hash exceeds some difficulty? *(not necessarily the difficulty provided)*